# Get data from a API URL in HTML or JSP using Javascript or Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, azure

I have an API [url](https://shopunter.azure-mobile.net/api/choco/me) (pls see the link) , which return me some data . I need to call that API from a HTML and want display that response in HTML. I have tried multiple examples of using Ajax and java script. Could any one suggest a working thing to do this stuff.  I am using Microsoft azure mobile service in back end.I am even okay with solution in JSP

Comment: Please share the code you're using and also tell about any errors you're getting. One thing that comes to my mind is if you have enabled CORS for your mobile service to allow cross-domain requests.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://shopunter.azure-mobile.net/api/choco/me. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message posted in the comments, it is clear that CORS is not enabled. Please enable CORS on your Mobile Service API so that cross-domain requests can be processed. You may find this link useful for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn155871.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I am trying from local host. Added "localhost" in ALLOW REQUESTS FROM HOST NAME. Still issue persists :(